# How to keep only one instance of Google Maps for iOS tab view controller

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

How can I use only one instance of Google Maps for the iOS tab view controller?

I have different tabs within the tab view controller and some of the use the Google Maps iOS SDK. For memory reasons I just want to keep one instance of the mapView.

I'm writing my code in Swift 4.

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar issue in my previous projects. I had map screen and detailed map screen. I reused `GMSMapView` for the both screens. Common manager was filtering the map's data on entering/exiting the ViewController. So you can detect selecting of new tabs in your TabViewController and apply your changes to your mapView. This will ease your memory loading, especially if you use a lot of notations with your mapView.

Edit with sample code snippet:

Here is a sample code snippet

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if self.mapView?.superview != self.mapViewContainer {
            self.mapView?.placeFullScreenInView(self.mapViewContainer)

            ... // some VC logic handling appearance of the mapView and business logic here
        }
}`
```

More info:
Views:

```
@IBOutlet private weak var mapViewContainer: UIView! // UIView - container of the GMSMapView
weak var mapView: GMSMapView! // the shared GMSMapView between the controllers; In my case I passed this view in prepareForSegue because it was the easier way: VC -> (push) Detailed VC. You might need separate class managing this transfer.
```

Custom Methods

```
placeFullScreenInView - pretty self explanatory - placing the mapView as a subview with 4 constraints to the top, right, bot, left (0) in mapViewContainer.
```

In my base first VC I have also the same logic of mapView/mapViewContainer and:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        self.map?.removeFromSuperview()
        //... logic for nullifying not needed data
    }
```

Comment: How did you pass your mapView to your different tabs?

Comment: I have edited my code with some sample code. If you have any further question, please do not hesitate to ask :)